# Asp.net calendar do not render previous/next days

Tags: asp.net, controls, calendar, web-controls

How to do it. For example the calendar for march will also show days from feb and april. I dont want them to be shown. How to do. Anyone have sample code?

Comment: Not sure if its possible, but javascript calendars such as extjs, or jquery ui offer a much better solution generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DayRender event, check the date.  If it falls in the previous or the next month, make the cell's text a `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void objCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    CalendarDay d = ((DayRenderEventArgs)e).Day;

    TableCell c = ((DayRenderEventArgs)e).Cell;
    if (d.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        c.Controls.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
            //stuff
    }
}
```